# Google App Engine Datastore Admin

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, admin

When I try to access the Datastore Admin page in my GAE app, i get the following error

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.
```

I have switched it on in my app.yaml

```
builtins:
- datastore_admin: on
```

I am not even able to download data from the datastore. I get the error Authentication failed.
What could be the reason ?

Comment: Check your admin console's log page. Exceptions are shown there, not in the response body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is something to do with using custom domain. When I create a normal application and upload the code, it works fine. Only when I have a custom domain, i get the problem

Answer (score 2):

look at the procedure in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin).

Maybe you forgot to add :

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

Hope it help!

Comment: @GuidoGarcía the link has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the apps's authentication method from Google Apps Domain to Google Accounts API and it now works.